# Jenkins : pipeline not moving ahead after User input step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My Jenkinsfile looks like below:

```
pipeline {

    agent any 
    
    stages {
        stage("Get Branches from Git"){
            steps{
                     sh """
                        git branch -a | grep remotes > ${WORKSPACE}/branchesList.txt
                     """  
               }
            }
        
        stage('User Input'){
           steps{
               script{
                   listBranchesAvailable = readFile 'branchesList.txt'
                    env.branchToDeploy = timeout (time:1, unit:"HOURS") {
                        input message: 'Branch to deploy', ok: 'Confirm!',
                                parameters: [choice(name: 'Branches Available:', choices: "${listBranchesAvailable }", description: 'Which branch do you want to build?')]
                        }
               }     
           }       
        }
        stage('Checkout Code'){
            steps{
                cleanWs() // ensure workspace is empty
                git branch: "${branchToDeploy}", changelog: false, credentialsId: 'my-creds-Id', poll: false, url: "${GIT_URL}"

            }
        }
        stage("Build") {
            steps{
                echo "Starting Build stage"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a User Input stage to choose the branch from a drop down list of branches.
However, the pipeline gets stuck at User Input stage and doesn't go the next stage even after giving the input. Am I missing anything here ? Please let me know

Comment: Do you get any error in the logs?

Comment: Just observed that the pipeline moves ahead if I go to the console output , click on Input Requested and provide input. Not from the stage view ... Strange ..